# How can I play music successively in the background with UIWebView or WKWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, hybrid-mobile-app, wkwebview, hybrid

The website implemented inside my app would play a series of mp3 files,it works well when the app is active,but when I press HOME button or lock the phone,it cannont play more than ONE song in the background,after that,app suspended.
I've already tried to set different kind of `AVAudioSession Category`，but of no use.

Comment: Did you find an sulotion?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you don't have `audio` background mode enabled. This is what [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) says:

> When the UIBackgroundModes key contains the audio value, the system’s media frameworks automatically prevent the corresponding app from being suspended when it moves to the background. As long as it is playing audio or video content or recording audio content, the app continues to run in the background. However, if recording or playback stops, the system suspends the app.

So it seems like you just need to enable `audio` background mode. Here is [Ray Wenderlich's tutorial on background modes](https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I've already enable audio background mode in the target's capabilities settings.